# Display data in a pop-up and print the page

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

By clicking on a button named " generate report" or "summarize" some sort of pop-up would show summarizing the collected data showing value like average, total, etc... it also comes with a graph. On the corner of the page displaying summarized results there would be a print button to print the summary page

How would I open a new window/tab or some sort of section to display the report?
And how would i be able to print it in the same format as it is?

Comment: use window.open() to create a popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI dialog to create modal popup. Inside of this dialog you can put everithing you need. But if need to pring it - better create in js new window and put information there:

```
window.open();
```

To print browser window content just call in onClick for your button:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onClick="window.print();" />
```

For graphical information I prefer jqPlot. Try it - that is nice tool. See demo [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/).

If you need high quality printing than generate pdf or xlsx. If you use java and tomcat you can easilly integrate JasperServer to your application.

Comment: thanks a lot! didn't encounter window.print() when searching dunno why O_O. the jqPlot is great as well